# Separate all values from Iterable, Apache Spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I have grouped all my customers in `JavaPairRDD<Long, Iterable<ProductBean>>` by there customerId (of Long type). Means every customerId have a List or ProductBean.

Now i want to save all ProductBean to DB irrespective of customerId. I got all values by using method
 `JavaRDD<Iterable<ProductBean>> values = custGroupRDD.values();`

Now i want to convert `JavaRDD<Iterable<ProductBean>>` to `JavaRDD<Object, BSONObject>` so that i can save it to Mongo. Remember, every BSONObject is made of Single ProductBean.

I am not getting any idea of how to do this in Spark, i mean which `Spark's Transformation` is used to do that job. I think this task is some kind of `seperate all values from Iterable`. Please let me know how is this possible.
Any hint in Scala or Python are also ok.

Comment: It's a  simple Java Iterable, you can do it like any other iteration on collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `flatMapValues` function:

```
JavaRDD<Object,ProductBean> result = custGroupRDD.flatMapValues(v -> v)
```

Comment: Thanks, i did the same thing.  
`JavaRDD<ProductBean> flatMap = values.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Iterable<ProductBean>, ProductBean>() {
   @Override
   public Iterable<ProductBean> call(Iterable<ProductBean> t)
     throws Exception {
    return t;
   }
  });`